# AWS Glue Crawler Creates thousands of tables with the exact same schema

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I have an integration with an external company that is sending me files like:

```
[{"id": "123", "person": { "name": "jimmy", ...}, "location":{ "state": "MA", ...}}]
```

Each file they push into S3 is an array like this, and the schema is the same for each file. The path is just `s3://bucket/data-lake/companyname/[UUID]-[date].json`. I want to be able to query across all these files in Athena, but can't bc the root of the file is an array instead of being ndjson. Cool, so I figure I'll create a glue job that outputs the files somewhere in ndjson format.

I created a Glue Crawler with a JSON classifier like `$[*]`, which strips out the top level array. Cool deal. However, when I run the crawler it outputs a couple of thousand tables, all with the same exact schema. There are about 150k files in that bucket/directory, so 2k tables means some schemas are being combined and some aren't.

My crawler configuration looks like:

```
Create a single schema for each S3 path:    true
Schema updates in the data store:   Update the table definition in the data catalog for all data stores except S3. For tables that map to S3 data, add new columns only.
Object deletion in the data store:  Ignore the change and don't update the table in the data catalog.
```

It doesn't seem like I can create a Glue job without an input table, and I can't make the input table without a Glue Job - not sure where to go from here.

Comment: have you tried to run the crawler on less number of files with the desired schema

Comment: Have you tried using unnest operator with Athena which eliminates Glue job?